# Does OR clause suppress indexes in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, indexing

Does OR clause suppress Indexes, If yes can someone provide appropriate example?

```
create table test2(field1 varchar2(100),field2 varchar2(100),
                   field3 number,field4 varchar2(100));

create index test2_idx1 on test2(field1);

create index test2_idx2 on test2(field3);

declare
  j number :=1;
begin
  for i in 1..500000 loop
    insert into test2 (field1,field2,field3,field4)
    values('field1='||j,'field2='||i,j,'field4='||‌​i);
    if (i mod 1000)=0 then 
      j:= j+1;
    end if; 
  end loop;
  commit;
end;

EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('user', 'test2');

select * from test2 where field1='field1=1' or field3=1;
```

Comment: create table test2(field1 varchar2(100),field2 varchar2(100),field3 number,field4 varchar2(100));
/
<BR>
create index test2_idx1 on test2(field1);
/
<BR>
create index test2_idx2 on test2(field3);
/
<BR>
declare
j number :=1;
begin

for i in 1..500000 loop
insert into test2(field1,field2,field3,field4)values('field1='||j,'field2='||i,j,'field4='||i);

if (i mod 1000)=0 then
    j:= j+1;
end if;

end loop;
commit;
end;
/
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('user', 'test2');

select * from test2 where field1='field1=1' or field3=1;
/

Comment: Here OR Clause suppress index, pls advice

Comment: I tried your sample and works for me. I answered below with a screenshot.

Answer (score 9):

No, the use of the `OR` clause does not cause an index not to be used.
The `OR` clause only splinters the filtration decision path, and can be very costly for this depending on the complexity of the query & data involved.

Comment: With bitmap indexes, OR can use indexes and be very fast. Of course bitmap indexes have other drawbacks, depending on the situation.

Comment: Hi Kemp, find the example where or suppress the index.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what prompted you to ask this question but remember:

"Full scans are not always evil; indexes are not always good"
(Tom Kyte in "Effective Oracle by Design")

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a UNION between both clauses and it will be easier to make indexes work

```
select * from test2 where field1='field1=1' union select * from test2 where field3=1;
```

Anyway I run your sample script and the index is being used.

[image: it works in my machine]